# Vanilla ProxyConnect installation and configuration with application developed in pure PHP

Tags: php

It is first time i am using vanilla forum, i am using vanilla forum with my application developed in pure php, I just download ProxyConnect plugin and added the plugin in vanilla plugin folder and activated this plugin. I want to configure ProxyConnect plugin.

Can anyone help me Please!!!

Answer (score 1):

@chris is sort of right. I spent a little bit too long tracking this down, but I ended up getting 2.0.17.9 and ProxyConnect 1.8.4 working together, again. What's interesting is the change to the core is only in the unstable branch, which happens to be the one zipped up and plastered all over the Vanilla Forums site/blog. In any case, @Todd didn't leave a whole lot of details with the commit that (likely indirectly) broke `Gdn_CookieIdentity::GetCookiePayload` (which is what's causing the blank `GDN_User inserts` issue, too), so I'm not totally sure why the change was made. The re-factored method is much tighter, but it doesn't leave much room for plugins with cookie dependancies.

Basically, the method completely discards everything that ProxyConnect explicitly stores in the cookie before it redirects to /entry/handshake/proxy, paralyzing the half-authorized user in the database. Unfortunately, I didn't think to browse the repository until after I'd found and fixed the problem, so hopefully this'll help someone else.

File: `library/core/class.cookieidentity.php` 
Relevant commits: [`b537305`](https://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/commit/b5373055a2affedf62fc186f21c215ebdd37202d) & [`17f991a`](http://github.com/vanillaforums/Garden/commit/17f991a081d04725b105a936c6ac2beb97aeee9e)

```
public static function GetCookiePayload($CookieName, $CookieHashMethod = NULL, $CookieSalt = NULL)
{
   if (!self::CheckCookie($CookieName)) return FALSE;

      $Payload = explode('|', $_COOKIE[$CookieName]);

+     array_shift($Payload);
+     array_shift($Payload);
+     array_shift($Payload);
-      $Key = explode('-', $Payload[0]);
-      $Expiration = array_pop($Key);
-      $UserID = implode('-', $Key);
-      
-      $Payload = array($UserID, $Expiration);

      return $Payload;
}
```

Comment: is the fix to revert the function to previous method? Are you using the 1.9.9 version now? Vanilla's since changed that function once again... :(

Comment: This is all very old at this point and I've found myself much further away from the particular project that I implemented this into.

Answer (score 0):

[Have you tried referencing this comprehensive introduction](http://vanillaforums.org/page/singlesignon) and the [complete documentation](http://vanillaforums.org/page/ProxyConnect_SSO) it links to?

Answer (score 0):

ProxyConnect's manual integration does not work on any version above 2.0.16